# SageMaker batchTransform MultiRecord error - Unable to parse data as JSON. Make sure the Content-Type header is set to "application/json"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, inference

I am trying to invoke sagemaker batch transform

Input file example.jsonl

```
{"number":"0060540745","brand_name":"XYZ","generic_keywords":"123"}
{"number":"0060540745","brand_name":"XYZ","generic_keywords":"123"}
{"number":"0060540745","brand_name":"XYZ","generic_keywords":"123"}
```

When i use batchStrategy as `SingleRecord` transform is working fine

When i try to change the batchStrategy as `MultiRecord`  I start to get the error

Error

```
Unable to parse data as JSON. Make sure the Content-Type header is set to "application/json"
```

If you check my job configuration i already set my contentType as mentioned.

how do i fix this issue

I tried with below content types like

```
"application/json"

"application/jsonlines"

"application/x+jsonlines"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think since you are setting to multirecord the input_fn has to be modified to handle jsonlines instead of json.